# sharepoint 2010 search not working

Tags: sharepoint

I am working on a sharepoint 2010 project 
The problem I am current have is the search function doesn't really work. Whatever I searched, the result was "We did not find any results for [the keywork I searched]". I have uploaded the documents and crawled the content source and the service is running on central admin. Any help will be appreciated.

Regards,
Bin

Comment: There is a StackExchange site dedicated to SharePoint - http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that the crawl didn't actually manage to crawl any content.  You may want to go into the crawl log and check for any errors that occurred.

The most common error is that the Default Content Access account doesn't have rights to connect to the content source.

Check the default content access account in Search Administration and make sure it has enough rights on the content source.